# Find all max values in an array of hashes and then store in a separate array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am new to programming and am using Ruby to get familiar with syntax and control flow.

The program I am working on wants me to puts the dvd name that has the longest playing time. Here is my code:

```
dvds = [
  {
    :dvd_name=>"x-men",
    :dvd_playing_time=>549,
    :times_played=>9.0
  },
  {
    :dvd_name=>"Pi",
    :dvd_playing_time=>549,
    :times_played=>6.0
  }
]
```

Both hashes have `dvd_playing_time` of `549`, so I want both `"x-men"` and `"Pi"` stored in an array. I tried `max_by`, but it only returns one `dvd_name`.

```
dvds.max_by { |length| length[:dvd_playing_time]}[:dvd_name]
```

Any help you can provide is fantastic!

Comment: It would have been clearer to have made the key `:dvd_length` `:dvd_playing_time`, as some readers, especially those for whom English is a second language, may think you are referring to `:times_played`. Also, it would have been better to have made the values of `:times_played` different for the two hashes.

Comment: Cary Swoveland, thank you for your suggestion. I will modify my symbol to be clearer then it is now.

Comment: I edited :dvd_length to :dvd_playing_time and also changed :times_played values different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three steps to get an answer.

- Determine the longest playing time, by [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)ing each hash `h` to `h[:dvd_length]` and then taking the [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) of those values.
- Use [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) to select the hashes `h` for which `h[:dvd_length]` equals that maximum playing time.
- `Enumerable#map` those hashes `h` with the maximum playing time to `h[:dvd_name]`.

```
length_of_longest = dvds.map { |h| h[:dvd_length] }.max
  #=> 549
puts dvds.select { |h| h[:dvd_length] == length_of_longest }.map { |h| h[:dvd_name] }
  # x-men
  # Pi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in one line:

```
dvds.group_by{ |dvd| dvd[:dvd_playing_time] }.max.last.map{ |dvd| dvd[:dvd_name] }
```

This code groups the dvds by length, takes the group with the max length, and maps it to only contain the dvd names. It's not the fastest option since it'll run through the array a few times (n + g + m times, technically).

If you're concerned about speed:

```
max = 0
longest = []
dvds.each do |dvd|
  if dvd[:dvd_playing_time] > max
    max = dvd[:dvd_playing_time]
    longest = [dvd[:dvd_name]]
  elsif dvd[:dvd_playing_time] == max
    longest << dvd[:dvd_name]
  end
end
```

This algorithm, while inelegant, will give you the answer with a single iteration through the array, which is the best you can do.

Comment: Very nice answer. 1) It's perhaps worth noting (when discussing #2) that #1 requires between 2 and 3 passes through the array. 2) While `max` in #1 is fine, `max_by(&:first)` might be clearer. 3) In #2, you might write `dvds.each_with_object([]) do |dvd, longest| ...` so that you don't have to add `longest` at the end if, for example, you wrap it in a method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland do you know if each_with_object will be okay with me passing a new reference to `longest` when a new max is found and the old array has to be discarded? i was worried it would force me to use the same array, which would be slower.

Comment: It's not an issue of speed. It just won't work with `longest = [dvd[:dvd_name]]` when `longest` is a block variable.  (The assignment changes `longest`'s `object_id`.) In that case you need  `longest.replace([dvd[:dvd_name]])`. (`longest << dvd[:dvd_name]` is OK.) Also, you have a typo: the right bracket in `dvd[:dvd_length == max]`  is misplaced.

Comment: @eiko - I tried your algorithm and it only returned "x-men" and not both "x-men" and "Pi." Your dialogue with caryswoveland is over my head at the moment so maybe you both talked about returning one dvd name. Regardless, you gave me new material to understand so thank you very much!

Comment: @aprogrammer, did you remember the solution is held by the array `longest`, and `longest` is not returned by the `dvds.each do` block. Add `longest` as a separate final line.

Comment: @caryswoveland - I remembered and so added `puts longest` on a separate line to verify both "x-men" and "Pi" were stored. Not sure why only one dvd name was returned.

Comment: @aprogrammer i had made a typo which broke the algorithm, but i've fixed it. sorry about that!